# Нужна библиотека или исходники для формирования двумерного штрих кода DataMatrix

Tags: delphi

Нашёл библиотеку для QR кода

`https://github.com/perevoznyk/quricol`

Может быть есть что-то подобное для формирования DataMatrix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После долгого поиска было найдено решение

`https://github.com/JanOosting/delphidmtx`